# Нет либы для boost::asio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

Пути к boost и к либам есть[image: пруфы]

Некоторые другие части boost работают, например, boost::numeric::ublas::io

Установка boost'а проводилась так как должна проводиться, делал по гайду.

Вот настройки самого проекта [image: найстройки проекта]

При компиляции выводит ошибку:[image: ошибка]

Компилировал в Debug x64.
Той либы который просит vs реально нет в папке с либами, есть только аналог "libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_69.lib".
В чем дело? Как пофиксить это? Если нужны доп данные, то напишу.

Comment: Собери фулл и не парься.

Comment: @MrBin я качаю фулл библиотеку boost, там тупо нет того файла что просится компилятором

Comment: Ты можешь собрать вручную из сорсов. На официальном сайте есть мануал. Это займет не так много времени, но у тебя будет под x34-64, multi/single thread, debug/release. Т.е. около 6 вариантов для одной либы в среднем. Хедеры в бустер сами разбираться что подключать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как итог, скорее всего при компиляции библиотеки что-то идет не так. Скачал "Prebuilt windows binaries." с оф сайта boost c++ (тыкаем в more downloads..., в пункте other downloads "Prebuilt windows binaries.", качаем то, что нужно для вашей версии ms vs)